# Употребление причастий вместо нормативных в данных случаях отглагольных прилагательных

Tags: орфография, прилагательные

При чтении некоторой книги (уточню, что она является переводом и, следовательно, особо доверять такому источнику не приходится) заметил одну особенность, связанную с тем, что вместо отглагольного прилагательного "раненый" почему-то используется причастие "раненный", которое, как заявлено во всех справочниках, должно подчиняться общему правилу написания особой форм глагола несовершенного вида (в данном контексте слово "раненый" я рассматриваю как производное от глагола несовершенного вида, хотя он является двувидовым, что может быть причиной проблемы) и, соответственно, употребляться только в тех случаях, когда есть множество зависимых слов. Вот отрывок предложения, вызвавшего сомнения:

“...на ступеньках, ведущих к чаше, сидят люди, ране**нн**ые, перевязанные“.

Теперь изложу свои гипотезы по данной проблеме:

1. Связано ли такое написание с тем, что глагол "ранить" двувидовой? То есть можно ли считать, что здесь причастие употреблено потому, что произошло от глагола совершенного вида "ранить"? Это бы объяснило ситуацию, однако, как я уже прочитал в различных справочниках, от глагола "ранить" принято образовывать прямым образом **только** отглагольное прилагательное, вопреки тому, что исходный глагол двувидовой. Причастие "раненный", в свою очередь, употребляется, по их мнению, только при наличии зависимых слов.
2. Означает ли такое написание, что вместо отглагольных прилагательных могут употребляться соответствующие причастия, чтобы заострить внимание именно на **совершённости** действия без использования зависимых слов? Опять же, вряд ли такое возможно из-за правила, изложенного выше.
3. Имеет ли такое написание связь с наличием обособленных определений, одно из которых — причастие и является однородным по отношению к нашему слову? Мне такой вариант всё же кажется абсурдным, так как прилагательные могут спокойно употребляться с причастиями, характеризуя предмет.

Наиболее склоняюсь к первой теории. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если бы это была батальная сцена (затишье после боя), то по стилю больше подходило бы *"... сидят люди, среди них раненые с повязками*", где люди - обобщающее слово для сидящих, а раненые - *существительное* для части этих людей. Но в этом произведении описывается какой-то странный сон и сбивчивое описание видений; причастие "*раненные*" указывает на часть попавшихся на заметку сновидящего людей: *их ранило, подумалось ему*; а вот - если присмотреться - ещё и перевязанные (причастие, коррелированное по форме с первым). Думаю, что можно списать грамматические нестрогости на смутность и отрывочность видений, которые "авторски" (пусть для переводчика) здесь важнее присутствия "зависимых слов" и прочих премудростей.

Comment: В общем, Вы настаиваете на второй теории. Спасибо за мнение!